# Multiple images in accessoryView of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am trying to display multiple images in a cell of same sizes 24x24. I have put them in a loop like this:

```
cell!.accessoryView = UIView()
for url in arrURL {
    cell!.accessoryView?.addSubview(UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_play_circle_outline")))
}
cell!.accessoryView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24 * CGFloat(arrURL.count), 24)
```

But unfortunately, it displays only one image and there exists empty space afterwards for remaining images. Here is the layout:

[image: table cell]

There is an empty space on right side of the play icon. Any idea why this happening?

Comment: aren't you putting those subviews on top of each other? you're not giving the frame for the subviews you're adding, so they must be placed on top of each other

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin hmm... I will give it a try and update you here.

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin Your idea works... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @EugeneZhenyaGordin comment, I have tried giving the frame to subviews and it works. Here is my sample code:

```
cell!.accessoryView = UIView()
var i = 0
for url in arrURL {
      let myView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_play_circle_outline"))
      myView.frame = CGRectMake(i>0 ? 24 * CGFloat(i) : 0, 0, 24, 24)
      cell!.accessoryView?.addSubview(myView)
      i+=1
}
cell!.accessoryView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24 * CGFloat(arrURL.count), 24)
```

Here is my layout:

[image]